# I cannot find my production account for DocuSign

Tags: docusignapi

I have created a developer account for DocuSign and I have passed the review for API. But when I go live, I must log in with my production account.

I have joined the ISV Partner for Docu Sign and got an Account-Id for Partnership. But I haven't got a production account with username and password. I don't know how to get it. Can someone tell me how or where to find my production account?

Answer (score 0):

If you are an ISV Partner, you should have an account already, did you try to just click "forgot my password" on the https://account.docusign.com  with your email address? or search your email for an activation of your new account?

Or, if you don't yet have an account, email [partners@docusign.com](https://mailto://partners@docusign.com) to make sure you're a partner and they'll get you the account.